# Best Way to View Output of Glue Jobs for PySpark Scripts

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

So I created a job which calls a Python scripts and does PySpark transformations. However, when I view the `Output` from AWS Cloudwatch, the output has lots of info that is not important for me. For example:

```
at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(NewHadoopRDD.scala:199)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(NewHadoopRDD.scala:196)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
```

It there a way to configure Glue job to only output to the logs statements such as from the `print()` that I set or due to errors or exceptions only?

Comment: have you tried enabling Continuous Logging https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuous-logging-enable.html and Logging Application-Specific Messages Using the Custom Script Logger ?

Comment: This is the results with `Continuous Logging` enabled. Now I want to filter those log results for easier debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS recently released an update to Glue for V2.0. This version changed how logs are sorted/grouped and now the logs that I only want to see(e.g. from print()) are now put together in a single place where I can view easily in AWS Cloudwatch.

So the solution is to update your Glue job to use Glue 2.0.